# Android Load html file to local server

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I want to make Android App, which will run its local `HTTP server`. Through this server I want to load `index.html` to `WebView`. `index.html` is not working on its own. It is web app and has to be initialized on localhost. Also it is running other .js files inside `assets` folder.

To run this before I used python HTTP server and run it in browser from there.

I used `Ktor` library to create simple HTTP server but it shows just blank page. I don't know if I'm on right path with this solution at all.

My entire App:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import io.ktor.application.install
import io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.gson.gson
import io.ktor.http.content.default
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.netty.Netty

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webView: WebView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view)
        initHttpServer()
        initWebViewContent()
    }

    private fun initHttpServer(){
        embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                gson {}
            }
            routing {
                default("/app/src/main/assets/index.html")
            }
        }.start(wait = true)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun initWebViewContent(){
        webView.apply {
            loadUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                    view.loadUrl(url)
                    return false
                }
            }
            settings.apply {
                setSupportZoom(true)
                builtInZoomControls = true
                displayZoomControls = false
                javaScriptEnabled = true
                javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok I dont need HTTP server - index.html can be loaded as:
`webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")`

`index.html` is placed inside `/app/src/main/assets/` subfolder which is default asset folder for Android project.

Comment: `want to make Android App, which will run its local HTTP server. ` You just said that you wil run a http server on your Android device. The same device as your Android app is running on. Local: on the same device.

Comment: Normally I want to run fully developed web app exported as html from other environment. All of its logic is coded in javascript. Android App is just displaying content.

Comment: But it needs to be run on localhost. So yeah, I want local http server in Android App.

Comment: `default("/app/src/main/assets/index.html")` That is not a valid file system or resource file path for an Android app.

Comment: If you have an index.html file you can put it in assets at designtime and directly load it in your webview at runtime. No need for a server then.

Comment: Loading this index.html from resources is not working. Blank page. I cant even run it in browser if its not loaded to localhost

Comment: Show the code where you try to load from resource. A browser on your Android device cannot load a file from the resources of your app. It is unclear what you mean with its not loaded to localhost and about wich localhost you are talking.

Answer (score 1):

```
class AssertFileContent(
    private val context: Context,
    private val path: String
) : OutgoingContent.ReadChannelContent() {

    override val contentLength: Long?
        get() {
            val inputStream = context.assets.open(path)
            val available = inputStream.available()
            inputStream.close()
            return available.toLong()
        }

    override fun readFrom() = context.assets.open(path).toByteReadChannel()

}

private const val pathParameterName = "static-content-path-parameter"

fun Route.assetsFiles(context: Context, path: String = "") {
    get("{$pathParameterName...}") {
        val relativePath =
            call.parameters.getAll(pathParameterName)
                ?.joinToString(File.separator, prefix = path)
                ?: return@get
        try {
            val content =
                AssertFileContent(context, relativePath)
            call.respond(content)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        }
    }
}

// Application.routing
static("/") {
    assetsFiles(context, "/webapp")
}

// assets folder structure
webapp
  - index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serve using a file that doesn't exist. `assets` folder are packaged into APK and you can only access it through [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager). `Ktor` doesn't know about [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager) and uses standard facilities to access local files.

I suggest copying all the web resources to internal storage and serve from there ([filesDir](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) is the path to the root directory):

```
private fun copyWebResources() {
    val files = assets.list("web")

    files?.forEach { path ->
        val input = assets.open("web/$path")
        val outFile = File(filesDir, path)
        val outStream = FileOutputStream(outFile)
        outStream.write(input.readBytes())
        outStream.close()
        input.close()
    }
}
```

For the server, you can use the following setup:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, 3333) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {}
    }
    routing {
        static("static") {
            files(filesDir)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is example of `assets` folder structure:

```
web
  index.html
  script.js
```

Example URL for `loadUrl` is `http://127.0.0.1:3333/static/index.html`.

Also, there is a full sample [project](https://github.com/Stexxe/ktor_webview).

Answer (score 0):

I see that the OP problem is fixed with local access but for anyone who genuinely want to have a web server on an android device to get to from other devices, this is what I ended up doing.

I read the html from asset using `AssetManager` and then serve that up with ktor:

```
routing {
    get("/") {
        val html = application.assets.open("index.html").bufferedReader()
            .use {
                it.readText()
            }
        call.respondText(html, ContentType.Text.Html)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun copyFile(context: Context,filePath: String){
val file = context.assets.open(filePath)
val outFile = File(context.filesDir, filePath)
val outStream = FileOutputStream(outFile)

file.copyTo(outStream)
outStream.close()}

private fun copyDir(context: Context,path:String){
val assets = context.assets
val asset = assets.list(path)

asset?.forEach { list ->
    val listPath = "$path/$list"
    //文件夹
    if(!list.toString().contains(".")){
        println("Dir::$listPath")

        File(context.filesDir.path,listPath).mkdir()

        copyDir(context,listPath)
        return
    }
    println("File::$listPath")
    copyFile(context,listPath)
}}

fun main(){
File(context.filesDir.path,"www").mkdir()
copyDir(context,path = "www")}
```